# Code creating clustered columnstore index while maintaining row order

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, columnstore

I want to convert a rowstore table to a columnstore table by creating a clustered columnstore index. There are three columns in the table: id,time, and value.

The table is ordered by id and time before creating columnstore index; however, after creating columnstore index, the row order is messed up. I thought it might be due to the parallelism and added the `maxdop = 1` option, but that didn't fix the problem. Can anyone help me with this?

Here is the code creating tables and indexs:

```
-- creating rowstore table
drop table if exists tab1_rstore
select id, time, value
into tab1_rstore
from tab0
order by id_loan, period
option(maxdop 1)

-- creating clustered index on rowstore table
create clustered index idx on tab1_rstore (id,time)

-- creating columnstore table 
select * 
into tab1_cstore
from tab1_rstore
    option(maxdop 1)

-- comparing the first two rows from these two tables
    select top 2 *
from tab1_rstore

    select top 2 *
from tab1_cstore
```

The screenshot of the query results:

[image: Top two rows before c-index]

```
-- creating clustered columnstore index
create clustered columnstore index idx on tab1_cstore 
with (maxdop = 1) 

-- comparing the top two rows again
select top 2 *
from tab1_rstore

select top 2 *
from tab1_cstore
```

The screenshot of the query results with columnstore index:

[image]

My understanding is that the order of rows is determined by the compression algorithm and there is nothing we can do about it, see the limitation and restriction in the [document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492153.aspx) here with the following quote:

> Cannot include the ASC or DESC keywords for sorting the index.
>   Columnstore indexes are ordered according to the compression
>   algorithms. Sorting would eliminate many of the performance benefits.

I'm using SQL Server 2016 Developer Edition on Windows 10 64bit.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A clustered columnstore index is fundamentally different from a clustered rowstore index. You may have noticed there is no key column specification for a clustered columnstore index. That's right: a clustered columnstore index is an index with no keys - all columns are 'included'.

The most intuitive description I have heard for a clustered columnstore index is to think of it as a **column-oriented heap** table (where the 'RID' is `rowgroup_id, row_number`).

If you need indexes to support direct ordering and/or point/small range selections, you can create updateable rowstore b-tree indexes on top of clustered columnstore in SQL Server 2016.

In many cases this is **simply not necessary**, since columnstore access and batch mode sorting is so fast. Many of the things people 'know' about rowstore performance need to be relearned for columnstore. Scans and hashes are good :)

That said, of course columnstore has a structure to its row groups (and metadata about min/max values in each segment), which can be useful in queries that can benefit from row group/segment elimination.

One important technique in this area is to first create a clustered rowstore index with the desired ordering, then create the clustered columnstore index using the `WITH (DROP_EXISTING = ON, MAXDOP = 1)` option. In your example:

```
CREATE [UNIQUE] CLUSTERED INDEX idx 
ON dbo.tab1_cstore (id, time)
WITH (MAXDOP = 1);

CREATE CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX idx 
ON dbo.tab1_cstore
WITH (DROP_EXISTING = ON, MAXDOP = 1);
```

Care is needed to maintain the benefits of row group/segment elimination over time. Also, while columnstore is already implicitly partitioned by row group, but you can explicitly partition it as well.

I'm not 100% sure what you're looking to test, but it is true that the 'order' of values *within a segment* is determined by the compression algorithm. My point about creating the columnstore index with `DROP_EXISTING` is about the ordering of data flowing into the segment creation process, so that *segments overall* will be ordered in a particular way. Within the segment, all bets are off.

Answer (score 2):

As an aside, I believe the SQL Server Tiger Team is aware of the need for an `ORDER BY` clause or similar on columnstore index builds in order to maximize the opportunity for rowgroup elimination.

Also, at this time it is *very* important to make sure, as in [another answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/158660) here, that you use `MAXDOP = 1` when building the columnstore index. If you don't, you'll cause partitioning of the data into multiple threads that essentially reduces, perhaps dramatically, the possibility of the most efficient rowgroup elimination.